# android design : fragment or view?

Tags: android, view, fragment

When designing an Android app, the question often pops up : 
Is it better to design a given UI component as a view or as a fragment ?

Which criteria can be used to choose the 2 ? 
In which situation, in which case do you prefer one to the other ?

Note 1:
I know the format of this question may not been suitable for this stack site but I think the question is relevant for the community.

Note 2:
With this question, I am not really looking for a definitive answer (though I could be wrong), but I am looking for a collective reflection, experience sharing on that matter.

Comment: Maybe you were asking: Fragment or Activity? Well, nowadays it's mostly about Fragments, even with the support library, so... there's less occasions to use Activities, if not as Fragment containers. Yes, the Preferences aren't sill included in the support library, so, you still have to use an Activity for that. If you ever were to use a Splash screen, that would be probably an Activity, which launches the Main (which, in turn is a Fragment holder). I'd ultimately say: Fragments (as they represent the modern way of doing it).

Comment: what do Fragments have to do with Views? they are different beasts

Comment: @Vyger I'd still say 80% of my work is with Activities.  First off, fragments go inside of activities, so you won't have any fragments without one.  Secondly, fragments make a lot of sense if you're going to be majorly changing up the UI in different screen sizes/orientations or if you want to swap out large UI elements for each other.  But if you aren't doing that, they only complicate things.  Use them where appropriate, but I'd say they're appropriate in far less than half the apps I write.

Comment: No guys, I am really talking about fragments Vs views.

Comment: Aren't Views contained in Activities/Fragments? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Gabe: I hate Eclipse complaints for `deprecations`... I switched to Fragments. I only have the main Activity in which I replace Fragments and Fragments. And, of course, I also have the PreferenceActivity besides the Preference Fragment. **Only 2 Activities**, a bunch of Fragments and some Classes to hold common methods, variables, objects, ...

Comment: @Vyger I'd just turn them off with an annotation.  But Activity doesn't actually have any of those, because Activities aren't deprecated.  Using Fragments to do the jobs that should actually be done via a separate activity is actually bad design-  fragments have a purpose, but they don't replace Activities.  They're sub-activities which are controllers for a specific part of the workflow of an Activity.  Using them when you actually want a new workflow is wrong.

Comment: @Gabe: Annotations seems to me like cheating: "shut up, idiot!". The IDE forced me to switch to Fragments - Now I'm all with  Fragments. They suck, in my opinion (being much heavier than Activities), but that's it. Modern times, modern designs...

Comment: @Vyger Annotations aren't cheating.  Its like a warning in a C compiler-  it tells you something that may or may not be wrong, and you have to decide if it is or not.  If not, you tell it to shut up and move on.  Use fragments where they're needed and add functionality.  Don't use them where they aren't.  Especially since Activities aren't even deprecated in the first place-  I don't even know where you got that idea.

Comment: @Gabe: Because the IDE was ALWAYS complaining "You should be using Fragments!" "Fragments forever!" "Why aren't you using Fragments?!" - I broke my balls and switched to Fragments, so to make it happy. I don't find ANY valid reason for using Fragments (seriously, are there ANY?), but this is how I was forced to. FORCED by the IDE. Do I decided not to have it complain anymore (except when I MUST use Activities and HAVE TO turn annotations on).

Answer (score 1):

To answer you and get out of some of the nitpicking in comments:

*Views are onscreen elements.  Think of them as windows.  In a MVC pattern, they're the V.

*Fragments are controllers in a MVC pattern.  They typically own a bunch of views, and are used to define how the user interacts with those views in the program.

*Activities are controllers in a MVC pattern.  They can contain any number (including 0) of views or fragments.  Fragments are used to break up an activity into separate pieces if there's a big enough subset of easily separated functionality.