# Clearing the concepts regarding fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I think one can get everything from a simple android **Activity** that he can get from android **Fragment**. Is it extremely necessary to have knowledge about fragments?

Is it possible to do anything with Activities that one can do with Fragments? Are there reasons for when to prefer one over the other?

Comment: you can skip them, really, see the whole thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438854/android-design-fragment-or-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saad,

If you want to get expertise in Android development (Smartphone and tablet) then knowledge of fragments is essential. Its true that you can get work done without using fragments but when it comes to handling UI on larger screen like 7" or 10" tablets, fragments come handy.

And if you go through description given by Android for [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), its not that much difficult to understand it. Just start developing demos with fragment, you will see that Fragment are actually helping us in development

For your question: can I skip it?

yes you can